# Running Mongrel for Rails with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, mongrel

I'm trying to get my small rails application deployed. My VPS is running Apache 2.2 and I wish to direct requests through to a mongrel cluster to handle my new rails application.

Ruby version 1.9.3
Rails version 3.2.7
Mongrel version 1.2.0 (gem install mongrel --pre)

**What I've done**

I've started 3 mongrel daemons for ports 3001 through 3003 with the following:

```
mongrel_rails start -e production -p 3001 -d -P log/mongrel1.pid
```

respectively.

Something to note after running each start command; I get the following notices:

> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no
>   replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
>   Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:109.
>   NOTE: from_installed_gems(arg) is deprecated. From
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:63:in
>   `block (2 levels) in deprecate' NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is
>   deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after
>   2011-10-01. Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:50.
>   NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will
>   be removed on or after 2011-11-01. Gem::SourceIndex#each called from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:112.

My understanding tells me this shouldn't be a problem, but when I run:

```
ps aux | grep mongrel
```

I get:

```
someotheruser     17186  0.0  0.1 101064  1336 pts/0    S    12:56   0:00 su mongrel
mongrel  17187  0.1  0.3  67260  2872 pts/0    S    12:56   0:00 bash
mongrel  17284  0.0  0.1  65600   980 pts/0    R+   12:56   0:00 ps aux
mongrel  17285  0.0  0.0  61176   728 pts/0    R+   12:56   0:00 grep mongrel
```

I.e, I can't find the server process.

I've updated my vhosts to look like:

```
<proxy balancer://mongrelcluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
</proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.mydomain.co.uk
  ServerAlias subdomain.mydomain.co.uk
  ProxyPass / balancer://mongrelcluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mongrelcluster/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

When I direct my browser to subdomain.mydomain.co.uk I'm greeted with an Apache 403 error, but I can't tell where the error lies. It's likely that mongrel just isn't running as it should, but perhaps I've set my vhosts incorrectly.

Any help and/ or guidance appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As you seem to guess already: sounds like mongrel is not coming up. Did you check the `log/mongrel.log` and `log/production.log` files?

Comment: @iltempo Thanks, not sure why I didn't think to look there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the Mongrel log files and it appears that the issue was that my database.yml file was specifying the adapter as sqlite3 when it should have been mysql2. I didn't have sqlite3 installed and so Mongrel wouldn't start.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are missing a DocumentRoot specification inside your VirtualHost tag.